# Taking picture on command with webcam using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, camera, hardware, webcam

I am working on a project where I need to take a picture from a camera using a windows forms application. I have found many tutorials and frameworks ( like [Aforge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html) ) to do this, but I am unsure if this will work with all webcams.

For the project I need to take a 1080p image of a laser diffraction pattern. it is important that the camera does not do any image processing ( like adjust brightness , color correction , or automatically focusing etc ) , so I need a way to disable this or a camera which does not have those features.

so my questions are:

1. What is the best way to take a single image (no video ) from a webcame connected to the pc via usb using c# .
2. What camera should I buy for this ? (would [Logitech C920](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-960-000767-C920-HD-Webcam/dp/B006A2Q81M/ref=sr_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1437390343&sr=1-2&keywords=HD%20usb%20webcam) work ?)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used AForge library for taking photo from webcam. this is my little sample. I hope its helps. (sample created in Turkish language)

[webcam sample at yadisk](https://yadi.sk/d/CZVcfDT2ewsAM)

Comment: thanks for the sample :) , helped me understand how to use Aforge .

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot